# how to list files that I select using JScrollpane,JFilechooser,JList?

Tags: java, swing

I'm making a music player. I want to ask some questions.

[image]

In this picture(this is my player), I choose Choose Music button.
under the button, there is JScrollPane that shows music that I choose.
If i click that button, there are musics.

[image]

If I choose sample1.mp3 and sample2.mp3, musics are shown to JScrollPane like next picture.. ( My question is here, how to list the music on JScrollPane??)

[image]

If i double click each music(sample1,sample2), the music that I choose is playing ..(another question is here, how to play the music that I choose? I want the music's name that I choose.. like sample1,sample2 so I can play the music like C://sample1.mp3,C://sample2.mp3  format is C://'music name'.mp3  how to get that music name ??)

Comment: *"another question is here,.."* SO is a Q&A site, not a help desk. Each question should have a single, specific question that can be answered with a single answer.

Comment: *"how to list the music on JScrollPane?"* Put the `File` collection into a `ListModel` then set the list model to the list. Get it to render nicely (perhaps by trimming the extension and adding an icon) using a `ListCellRenderer`.

Comment: sorry .. now I can display that files.. I just want tips that how to get name that I doubleclick ..

Comment: I googled that File and defaultListModel , so I do it . Thanks for your answer

Comment: *"I just want tips that how to get name that I doubleclick "* That's completely different to **both** questions asked above! :-/ [edit] the question to the 3rd question you now want 'tips with'. BTW - did you do the tutorial on [How to Use Lists](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html)? It seems to cover this (latest) question.

Answer (score 0):

This is not my code , I got it somewhere when I was still in college feel free to use it.

Basically, you need custome `File` object operation, because by default JFileChooser doesn't have ability for that, if you want to do some filtering on files you can use [FileNameFilter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FilenameFilter.html)

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.io.File;
import javax.swing.*;

public class FileDemonstration extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JTextArea outputArea; 
    private JScrollPane scrollPane; 

    public FileDemonstration() {
        super("Get Current File demo");

        outputArea = new JTextArea();


        scrollPane = new JScrollPane(outputArea);

        add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER); 

        setSize(400, 400); 
        setVisible(true); 

        analyzePath(); 
    } 

    // allow user to specify file name
    private File getCurrentFile() {
        // display file dialog, so user can choose file to open
        JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
        fileChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);

        int result = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(this);

        // if user clicked Cancel button on dialog, return
        if (result == JFileChooser.CANCEL_OPTION)
            System.exit(1);

        File fileName = fileChooser.getSelectedFile(); // get selected file

        // display error if invalid
        if ((fileName == null) || (fileName.getName().equals(""))) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Invalid File Name",
                    "Invalid File Name", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            System.exit(1);
        } // end if

        return fileName;
    } // end method getFile

    // display information about file user specifies
    public void analyzePath() {
        // create File object based on user input
        File name = getCurrentFile();

        if (name.exists()) // if name exists, output information about it
        {
            // display file (or directory) information
            outputArea.setText(String.format(
                    "%s%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s%s\n%s%s\n%s%s\n%s%s\n%s%s", name
                            .getName(), " exists", (name.isFile() ? "is a file"
                            : "isn't a file"),
                    (name.isDirectory() ? "is a directory"
                            : "isn't a directory"),
                    (name.isAbsolute() ? "is absolute path"
                            : "isn't absolute path"), "Last modified: ", name
                            .lastModified(), "Length: ", name.length(),
                    "Path: ", name.getPath(), "Absolute path: ", name
                            .getAbsolutePath(), "Parent: ", name.getParent()));

            if (name.isDirectory()) // output directory listing
            {
                String directory[] = name.list();
                outputArea.append("\n\nDirectory contents:\n");

                for (String directoryName : directory)
                    outputArea.append(directoryName + "\n");
            } 
        } 
        else // not file /directory, display error
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, name + " does not exist.",
                    "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        } 
    } 

    public static void main(String args[]) {

            FileDemonstration application = new FileDemonstration();
            application.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


    } 

}
```

and for playing the music part, is not that simple since you need library for that.